# Assign a group number to a particular set of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe as given below

```
data1=[202,701,410,301,402,201,202,301,310,210,302,302,401,402,601,303]
data2=[210,303,500,302,403,202,203,303,400,300,303,310,402,410,203,801]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns = ['data1'])
df['data2'] = data2
```

which brings me the dataframe. 
Now I need to group the two columns with parent child relationship like below..

```
[201, 202, 203, 300, 210, 601],
[801, 301, 302, 303, 400, 310, 701],
[401, 402, 403, 500, 410]
```

I dont need the exact parent or exact child. I just want to group who all belong to same category in python 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html), last convert output to list of lists:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(df[['data1','data2']].itertuples(index=False))
```

Simplier is use [`convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html), thank you, @Dyz:

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'data1','data2')
```

---

```
connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

L = [list(x) for x in connected_components]
print (L)
[[201, 202, 203, 300, 210, 601], 
 [801, 301, 302, 303, 400, 310, 701], 
 [401, 402, 403, 500, 410]]
```

Comment: `g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'data1','data2')` is a better way to create a graph from a DataFrame.